# How to solve path issue for Spark Context? AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/opt/workspace/

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I am running JupyterLab on my MacOS. Part of the code:

```
new_list =[]        
for k in get_matching_s3_keys(bucket='cw-milenko-tests', prefix='Json_gzips/ticr_calculated_2', suffix='.gz'):
    new_list.append(k)
    

dfs = [spark.read.json(file) for file in new_list]

print (map(lambda df: len(df.schema), dfs))
```

I download from S3 then save to list. I got this error:

```
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/opt/workspace/Json_gzips/ticr_calculated_2_2020-05-27T00-01-21.json.gz;
```

This is the Spark cluster I use
[image]

I used this repo [spark cluster on docker](https://github.com/andre-marcos-perez/spark-cluster-on-docker)

How to check if my Docker containers communicate?

```
 docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
a01477cd9316        andreper/spark-worker:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bin/spa…"   4 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8082->8081/tcp                           spark-worker-2
f448de886c72        andreper/spark-worker:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bin/spa…"   4 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                           spark-worker-1
5789c47ef46e        andreper/jupyterlab:latest     "/bin/sh -c 'jupyter…"   4 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp                           jupyterlab
63e3d3c90ed6        andreper/spark-master:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bin/spa…"   4 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   spark-master
```

I checked the mount for jupyterlab and spark-master

```
milenko@Cloudwalkers-MacBook-Pro spark-cluster-on-docker % docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 5789c47ef46e
[{volume hadoop-distributed-file-system /var/lib/docker/volumes/hadoop-distributed-file-system/_data /opt/workspace local rw true }]
milenko@Cloudwalkers-MacBook-Pro spark-cluster-on-docker % docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 63e3d3c90ed6
[{volume hadoop-distributed-file-system /var/lib/docker/volumes/hadoop-distributed-file-system/_data /opt/workspace local rw true }]
```

How to upload this file to the corresponding path in HDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /local/path/to.json /hdfs/path/to.json` to add files to hdfs from local storage.

Add `file:///path/to/your.json` and check if spark can find it on your local file system.

Comment: How to find out what is my local path from jupyterlab?

Comment: It's printed on the error. `/opt/workspace/Json_gzips/ticr_calculated_2_2020-05-27T00-01-21.json.gz`